Speaker is not recognized on Ubuntu 24.04
My ThinkPad's e495 speakers are not recognized by Ubuntu 24.04. I tried to run some scripts, but so far it did not work.
AlsaMixer:


What scripts did you run? Where did they come from? Please edit the question and include the contents of these scripts.

I am not too sure which skripts i ran. But i can try to run some skripts to give out useful information about my system.

So I changed the sound card and unmuted the Speakers and now it gives me sound.
But if i reboot it sets the headphones again as default.

Please add more details.  Changed the sound card from what to what and why? Were the speakers muted before the card was changed?

I changed it from the default option to the second one. And then it showed way more sources and outputs then before. The speaker output was muted. But when I rebooted the system everything was quiet and set up as before.
